# IFTTT Webhooks doesn't allow localhopst

Tags: webhooks, ifttt

I am trying to build something that will allow IFTTT to send a web request to a localhost (127.0.0.1:8080) using webhooks. I have a web server running on my android device for this reason. The web server will then parse the request and forward this to the Tasker application as an event. My Kronaby watch has the ability to activate an IFTTT applet with a button push. In order to expand the possibilities, I am trying to integrate Tasker via a webhook.

The current issue I have is that webhooks doesn't allow requests to 127.0.0.1 per the error I am getting.

In the end my question would be how I could get IFTTT to send an action to Tasker.

Answer (score 0):

How would the IFTTT service - running on **their** servers know how to resolve **your** localhost (not running into their servers)?

I think you need to expose your server's IP address to (eg) IFTTT. Probably scary.

Comment: interesting point. Guess I would have to set up an ngrok tunnel.